# How will i achieve this in drupal

Tags: drupal, content-management-system

[Attached image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erwzt.jpg)

I have a view with items from a content-type listed in it. i want to group the items like the one in the image. how will i achieve that in drupal

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) , and [Views Glossary](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_glossary)

https://www.drupal.org/project/views

https://www.drupal.org/project/views_glossary